# How to use celery result_backend table in a DB

Tags: python, postgresql, celery

I am reading through the documentations on using a transactional DB to store task results. I am a little uncertain on how to go about that. Let's say I am using postgresql, I configure my celery application as specified in the documentation:

```
celery_app = Celery('my_app'
         , broker='amqp://localhost//'
         , backend='db+postgresql://user:password@localhost/db_name',
         , include=['my_app.my_task'])
```

Ok cool, but I am confused as to how to create that backend table in my postgresql DB. What is the DDL supposed to look like? What is the schema name? Table name? Columns+datatype within the table? I can't find anything related to these questions in the documentation. Please help

Comment: That will be handled by celery, the backend is used to store the task state/result. You just have to define the backend. More on that, read this: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you decide to use any SQLAlchemy supported database servers as your result backend, all you need to do is to give a valid, working URL for as *result_backend* value in the Celery configuration. Celery will automatically detect that the schema is not generated and do that on the first run.

Comment: thanks for the clarification on that bit but I am still unable to find the results backend tables in Postgresql. They are not in the public schema and I can't find them anywhere. From the docs here: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/reference/celery.backends.database.models.html, i know the tablenames are `Task` and `TaskSet`

Comment: Did you run any task?

Comment: I did. Some of the tasks have successfully finished according to flower and logs :(

Comment: Ninja edit: I noticed that the tasks are taking very long to finish if I include the `backend_result` parameter. I read that this is due to extra resources being used up to insert new entries into the table. I am wondering it is taking TOO long to insert those new task results? The object I am returning is a simple dict

Comment: If the worker does not show any errors in the log, you should have data in the database by now...

Comment: do you know which schema the tables are supposed to live in? This would help me with debugging

Comment: ok, found the answer. The tables are living in the public schema but I can change that by creating a new user for celery and giving it a default schema. It turns out that it just took a really long time to create the tables and that I was not pointing to the SSL/CA_cert certificates

Comment: @lollerskates, Its recommended by many professionals that we should not use the database as a result backend. This will affect the performance of your application if you are using the same database server for the application.

Comment: Note that if you use a DB result backend, you also need to install relevant libraries.
For example, I use postgresql, so I need:

pip install SQLAlchemy,

pip install psycopg2